# How to set Selected value to dropdown list from database PHP/SQL

Tags: php, mysql

I want to set selected values in dropdown list to the one im editing.

```
$id = $_GET['edit'];
    $result = $polaczenie->query("SELECT * FROM wizyty WHERE idwizyty=$id")
    or die($mysqli->error());
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $id = $row['idwizyty'];
        $data = $row['data'];
        $pracownik = $row['pracownik'];
        $usluga = $row['usluga'];
        $klient = $row['klient'];
        $time = $row['starttime'];
        $cena = $row['cena'];
    }
```

Dropdown list

```
<label>Pracownik</label>
                        <?php 
                            $query = "SELECT imie, nazwisko FROM `pracownicy`";

                            $wynik1 = mysqli_query($polaczenie, $query);
                        ?>
                        <select name="nowypracownik" value="<?php echo $pracownik; ?>">
                            <?php while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($wynik1)):;?>
                            <option selected="<?php echo $pracownik?>"><?php echo $row1[0] .' '. $row1[1] ;?></option>
                            <?php endwhile; ?>
                        </select><br><br>
```

I tried to do it like this but it's not working.

Comment: It's not working how? What are you getting now as opposed to the desired results?

Comment: `while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($wynik1)):;` < remove that trailing semi-colon, for one thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only value for ‘selected’ attribute is ‘selected’

```
 <option value="value" selected="selected">value</option>
```

So your code should look something like this

```
  <select name="nowypracownik" value="<?php echo $pracownik; ?>">
      <?php while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($wynik1));?>
      $value = $row1[0] .' '. $row1[1];
      $selected = $value == $pracownik ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
      <option <?php echo $selected?>><?php echo $value;?></option>
       <?php endwhile; ?>
   </select><br><br>
```

Comment: u forgot the <?php tag before $value but with it works! Thank you very much!